# jQuery FullCalendar accents in dayView

Tags: fullcalendar

I think this is a bug.
I setup the names (in italian) of days:

```
dayNames:['Domenica','Luned&igrave;', 'Martedì', 'Mercoledì', 'Giovedì', 'Venerdì', 'Sabato']
```

The name is shown correctly in the header of `dayView` but not in the subheader.
[image]

Does anybody know why?

Comment: Are you using some kind of frame's? Were is the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same problem. I solved by changing the function "htmlEscape" in file fullcalendar.js
I add:

```
.replace(/ì/g, '&igrave;')
```

the function now work correctly for me (i need the italian language in my application), but you must add the character to correctly encod in the day names

```
function htmlEscape(s) {
    return (s + '').replace(/&/g, '&amp;')
        .replace(/</g, '&lt;')
        .replace(/>/g, '&gt;')
        .replace(/'/g, '&#039;')
        .replace(/"/g, '&quot;')
        .replace(/ì/g, '&igrave;')
        .replace(/\n/g, '<br />');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Way simpler:
Add `<meta charset="utf-8">` to the `<head>` of your html file

Answer (score 0):

I tried the htmlEscape function modified by user3514257 but I found an error.

This is my function:

```
function htmlEscape(s) {
    return (s + '').replace(/ì/g, '&igrave;')
        .replace(/</g, '&lt;')
        .replace(/>/g, '&gt;')
        .replace(/'/g, '&#039;')
        .replace(/"/g, '&quot;')
        .replace(/&/g, '&amp;')
        .replace(/\n/g, '<br />');
}
```

I change the first line with the `ì` line because the `&` character did not allow recognizing of `&igrave;`

Comment: How is this different? You've swapped two lines? `ì` first instead of `&`? Doesn't seem to add anything.